# Angular 4 export enum with the namespace

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I'm trying to make a `enum` to handle country & currency codes.
The `enum` must be used through entire app (Ionic 3 Angular 4 app).

So far, i found this way:

```
enum CountryCode {
  TH,
  BGD,
}

namespace CountryCode {
  export function getCurrencyCode(country: CountryCode) {
    switch (country) {
      case CountryCode.TH:
        return 'THB';
      case CountryCode.BGD:
        return 'BDT';
      default:
        return 'THB';
    }
  }
}
```

however in this case the `enum` can't be exported to other modules.

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: add an export to your enum - export enum countryCode{}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be declaring it inside the namespace as below,

```
export namespace CountryCode {
    export enum CountryCode {
        TH,
        BGD,
    }
    export function getCurrencyCode(country: CountryCode) {
        switch (country) {
            case CountryCode.TH:
                return 'THB';
            case CountryCode.BGD:
                return 'BDT';
            default:
                return 'THB';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: when i do import - should i import a namespace or enum? strange - in `app.component.ts` import is working, but in `@Injectable()
export class UserData` with exactly same import - i get the error `Cannot find name 'CountryCode'`